# program hangs inside while loop for reading input stream from socket: Java

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, freeze

I have the following code to read an input stream from a socket connection:

```
private ByteBuffer toByteBuffer(BufferedInputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int l;
    byte[] data = new byte[256];
    while ((l = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, l);
    }
    buffer.flush();
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer.toByteArray());
}
```

In the first iteration of the while loop, everything goes fine and I am able to get the data into the buffer. But then it gets stuck at `while ((l = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {`

I think (and I might be wrong) it is because it is waiting for more data from the socket, which is never going to come.

How do I handle this situation/hang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `BufferedInputStream` method you are using does not block you get the situation that as soon as your `InputStream` does not have any data and is not closed you don't get a -1 but a 0.
This will send your method into an endless loop.

So for reading local streams it is better to check for `read() <= 0` as you usually get the data fast enough.
The best way is to make sure there is an `eof` by closing the stream.