# Where does this Java program get stuck?

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a Java client that sends a message to a server and receives the corresponding audio (text-to-speech) as a stream of bytes. I successfully find the audio in the "cache" directory, but my program just hangs without ending. It enters the while loop in the "receiveAudio" method and prints in the standard output the length of the message. If it was stuck inside the while I'd expect infinite prints, but it just prints it once. Also, it doesn't exit the while because I'd get "while finished" in the output if it did. I can't understand what's going on. I very rarely use java so I probably did some stupid mistakes. Below the code and a screen of the output I get.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String msg = "I don't know what to say";
        ConnectionThread c = new ConnectionThread(msg);
        c.start();
    }

    private static class ConnectionThread extends Thread {
        private String msg;

        ConnectionThread(String msg) {
            this.msg = msg;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
                PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                pr.print(msg);
                pr.flush();
                receiveAudio(s);
                s.close();
                System.out.println("Run finished");
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        private void receiveAudio(Socket s) throws IOException {
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
            byte[] msgByte = new byte[1000000]; 
            int totBytes = 0;
            boolean end = false;

            try {
                File dstFile = new File("cache/audio.wav");
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);

                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(msgByte)) > 0) {
                    System.out.println(len);
                    out.write(msgByte, 0, len);
                }
                System.out.println("while finished");
                out.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24619590/522444). It might have relevance.

Comment: It's stuck calling `in.read`, because `in.read` waits until there is some data.

Comment: You can find out where a program is stuck by getting a thread dump. You can use the `jstack <pid>` command to do that, where `<pid>` is the process id of your JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in.read` waits until there is some data to read, or the server closes the connection. (It returns 0 if the server closes the connection)

Since the server isn't sending any more data, and also isn't closing the connection, it waits forever.

You need to either make it so the server closes the connection after it sends all the data, or the server has some other way to tell the client when it's finished sending all the data (e.g. by sending the total number of bytes and then the client stops once it's read the right number of bytes).